# Is it possible to conditionally omit some of values yielded?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have a generator function for producing (fake) json data. To provide better data diversity, I'd like to programmatically set which nodes are or aren't generated. Is there a way to wrap logic around each of the `yield`'s template lines? I realize that the entire `yield` could be wrapped in logic, but the number of permutations would make that cumbersome.

```
def json_generator(length):
    for x in range(length):
        yield {'node1': x,
               'node2': x,
               'node3': x
               }
```

For this use case, would I be better off just appending each node to a string, with logic around the append?

Comment: what determines how many nodes are created? it is not clear from the function provided

Comment: What exactly do you want to yield? Every permutation of nodes?

Comment: Length is passed in as a parameter. It'll vary depending on the number of records to be created. Might be low for a smoke test; million+ for creating load test data. RE: node1...node 3. There would be ~2-3 dozen total. Goal is not to produce every permutation but to produce some variability. e.g. Perhaps every 20th record would produce node3 but not node2. And maybe node1 is output only every other record., etc.

Comment: if there is logic it's just a matter of implementation. you can always construct the dict beforehand following that logic and then just yield it. Also, you are yielding a dict, not JSON string.

Comment: Sure, just put the `yield` statement inside an `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're talking about:

```
def json_generator(length, add1=True, add2=True, add3=True):
    for x in range(length):
        r = {}
        if add1: r['node1'] = x
        if add2: r['node2'] = x
        if add3: r['node3'] = x
        yield r

for x in json_generator(10, False, True, True):
    print(x)
```

Result:

```
{'node2': 0, 'node3': 0}
{'node2': 1, 'node3': 1}
{'node2': 2, 'node3': 2}
{'node2': 3, 'node3': 3}
{'node2': 4, 'node3': 4}
{'node2': 5, 'node3': 5}
{'node2': 6, 'node3': 6}
{'node2': 7, 'node3': 7}
{'node2': 8, 'node3': 8}
{'node2': 9, 'node3': 9}
```

This preserves the original behavior if you create the generator with just the `length` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! That's a quick way to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for an algorithm/process

- Figure out what your rules are for excluding nodes
- Put the nodes in a Pandas Series
- Use one of the Numpy random methods to generate a boolean array - maybe use some kind of weighting to implement your rules
- use the boolean array to index/select items in the node Series

  - concatenate the results along with any other text to make a string and yield it

---

Alternatively keep the nodes in a list and use a built-in random method to choose a subset of nodes. Build a string from the ones that survive the cut.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! It sounds interesting but beyond my available time.